# subprocess.Popen() results taking a very long time to communicate() in Linux

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I'm working on a project where I am attempting to scan for any application communicating through TCP port 587. In windows, I was able to use the code below:

```py
import subprocess
from datetime import datetime

proc = subprocess.Popen('netstat -ano -p tcp | findStr "587"', shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(f'before proc.communicate(): {datetime.now()}')
out, err = proc.communicate()
print(f'after: {datetime.now()})
```

With these results:

```
before proc.communicate(): 2022-03-12 17:21:04.079038
after: 2022-03-12 17:21:12.411754
```

However, when I try to run an alternative command in Linux below:

```py
import subprocess
from datetime import datetime

proc = subprocess.Popen('lsof -nP -iTCP:587',
                        shell=True,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(f'before proc.communicate(): {datetime.now()}')
# this line is taking way too long to run
(out, err) = proc.communicate()
print(f'after: {datetime.now()}')
```

My results are as follows:

```
before proc.communicate(): 2022-03-12 14:31:23.652261
after: 2022-03-12 14:31:36.613435
```

I'm not sure using datetime is giving the most accurate results... When I run the command in Linux from my IDE (PyCharm), it takes several seconds to show the "after..." results while on Windows it is instant.
Any help to work this issue out or better understand what's going on is very much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Can't reproduce. This takes less .1s on my linux box.

Comment: You are probably experiencing buffering. The operating system collects the output, and only delivers a batch when the buffer fills up.

You can avoid this by specifying `bufsize=1` (or more generally a small number).

Comment: By the by, you are comparing apples and oranges; the `findstr` in your first command discards most of the output from `netstat`, and so you end up delivering much less to Python.

Comment: In the second case, `shell=True` is not providing any value, though you'll then need to split the command into a list of tokens, either manually or wrth `shlex.split()`.

Comment: Finally, don't use `Popen` when you can use one of the higher-level one-liners like `subprocess.check_output()`; the documentation also mentions this, right near the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Give [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) a try. This might solve slowness and provide python objects instead of raw text.

```
import psutil

psutil.net_connections(kind='tcp')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use netstat, and let Python do the text filtering.

I don't have a Linux box handy; this is the output on FreeBSD 13.

```
In [1]: import subprocess as sp

In [2]: %timeit sp.run(["netstat", "-an", "-p", "tcp"], capture_output=True, text=True)
3.04 ms ± 20 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [3]: r = sp.run(["netstat", "-an", "-p", "tcp"], capture_output=True, text=True);

In [4]: %timeit [ln for ln in r.stdout.splitlines() if ".587 " in ln]
6.81 µs ± 7.74 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [5]: port587 = [ln for ln in r.stdout.splitlines() if ".587 " in ln]
Out[5]: []
```

Note how running the external process takes a couple of milliseconds, but filtering the output only takes microseconds.